# Button is Not Appearing When Placing Below The GridView

Tags: android, xml, button, gridview

I Am Making a Layout In Android XML In Which I Want To Add a Button To The Bottom Of The Layout And The Whole GridView Above It But I Cannot Able To Do It !
Don't Know Why...
Can Anyone Help Me ?

### Here Is My XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <GridView
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:id="@+id/PhoneImageGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:scrollingCache="false"
            android:animationCache="false"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: full layout showing gridView ??

Comment: Yes, Absolutely !

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` try remove these two lines from the button

Comment: otherwise u can take in button `below` and remove on a Gridview `above`

Comment: Nothing Happens :(

Comment: which one nothing happens ? @AHmad

Comment: remove 2 line of a #SantanuSur says and try my comment

Comment: Didn't Work @MohammadAli

Comment: wait i'll put answer and u can only copy and cut in your code if work or not tell me ok

Comment: did you check removing the two lines ?? otherwise your layout looks perfect..

Comment: Removing Lines Didn't Worked For Me @SantanuSur :(

Comment: you could run the application and check..it worked or not..

Comment: I Checked ! But It Didn't Worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem Solved !

I Am The One Who Posted The Question. My problem Is Solved All This Was Due To An Attribute In My **ViewPager** Tag From The My Tabbed Activity's layout.

### The Attribute Was:

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

### In Tag:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

This Was Causing The Fault In Layout As The Layout Was Ending Below To The End Of Screen.
You Can See That 
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao8f1.png) !

I Removed That Attribute And Everything Become Alright !